# Unable to ssh using openstack

Tags: openstack

I have the following topology:

[image]

Basically 2 subnets, 10.0.27.0 and 192.168.0.0.
I have a floating ip that I assign to one of the machines using the interface in the 10.0.27.0 subnetwork, and it works fine. I added the rules for allowing the ssh traffic. However, when I try to do the same for the interface in the subnet 192.168.0.0, it doesn't work. After a nmap I can see that the port is closed, so I don't know what is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

So many possible reason,

1. Did subnet 192.168.0.0 has opened port? did you test it first?
2. Did you try to change the subnet into 192.168.0.1? test by changing the subnet into that first. Using default subnet end with 0.0 or 1.1 value sometimes in different environment cause a problem.

You may share what environment you setup this topology and how you do this?
Is it through virtualised network environment or using physical network (switches or router).